# How to loop through forms in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to create a Rails app where people can pick which sports teams will win that day. I can display all of the day's games and I can create a form to pick the winner for one game, but I am thus far unable to meld those two together to allow the user to see a list of all of the day's games with a radio button beside each team and make a selection on each of the games, then click a single submit button.

I have so far tried the below and several variations thereof.

```
<% @games.each do |game| %>

  <%= form_for @pick, url: {action: "index"} do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label(game.home)%>
      <%= f.radio_button(:winner, game.home) %>
      <%= f.label(game.away)%>
      <%= f.radio_button(:winner, game.away) %>
    <%= f.submit "Pick" %>
  </p>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Here's what I am aiming for:

```
Team A [X] vs. Team B [ ]
Team C [ ] vs. Team D [X]
Team E [ ] vs. Team F [X]

[Submit]
```

Also, is there a better way to do this using a gem or something else more straightforward?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't *loop through the form*. Instead *loop through the fields*.

```
<%= form_for @pick, url: {action: "index"} do |f| %>
  <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label(game.home)%>
      <%= f.radio_button(:winner, game.home) %>
      <%= f.label(game.away)%>
      <%= f.radio_button(:winner, game.away) %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Pick" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, though this appears to allow only one selection for all radio buttons on the page, rather than one for each pair of teams. Also, for some reason it always trips up on "game.home" when it's part of the form. Works fine when that code is outside of the form though.